# Jasper Reporting XLS generation in Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am trying to generate *Jasper reports using Java program*. Most of the times the cells aren't properly filled in the XLSX file (I have made sure in the iReport they(fields and titles) use the same widths). The text in the cells sometimes appears to be concatenated. Can someone help on how to insert data in a xls row properly.

Also need to know if querying data from jrxml is better or passing a list to jrxml is better (Performance wise).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "The text in the cells sometimes appears to be concatenated" is data missing or simply excel column needs to be expanded ?

Comment: The excel columns need to be expanded as per text size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports export to excel auto size columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987944/jasperreports-export-to-excel-auto-size-columns)